# Search for more then one numeric value in vim

Tags: vimrc

I am trying to search for numeric values in files. I use  / command to start my search (/34587). However I need to add more then one search criteria (i.e. finding value 3487 and 09087 for instance). What is the search command in vim for such scenarios? thank you

Answer (score 2):

There's no "special command" for that. You use just the same `/` (or `?`) but along with a special pattern called "a regular expression".

An introduction to this topic is written in the chapter 27 of Vim User Manual (`:h usr_27.txt`). Specifically, a section 27.5 "Alternatives" (`:h 27.5`). So in your case it is `/3487\|09087`.

Comment: thank you! works

Comment: @henrietta A great intro to regular expressions (or regex) in vim is [vimregex.com](http://vimregex.com/). It helped me a lot when I was first learning regex

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `\d`